# Need some RF help - integrating with a Xemics DP1203 transceiver

Tags: rf, transceiver

So there are some devices (timing photogates) that use these chips (DP1203C915) to send data out over RF at 915MHz to a box that performs timing and split-time calculations.  I would like to be able to read the data as well.

I was going to just buy a couple of the chips and play around with them, but am unable to find any domestic sources - they seem to be discontinued.

Any ideas on a contemporary component I could try to use instead to read the data?

I was thinking perhaps a software defined radio module would get me going...but then I currently have no idea how to go about decoding the signals into useful data...

Here is the data sheet: [DP1203 – 868 and 915MHz Drop-In RF Transceiver Modules](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/dp1203.pdf)

> Virtually no RF knowledge is required to use this RF
>   module. Wireless communication can be obtained
>   with just the addition of a suitable antenna and a
>   microcontroller. The DP1203 fulfils a wide range of
>   application requirements, ranging from basic point-topoint
>   communication to more complex multipoint
>   process control functions.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be difficult to find a replacement - this unit has to be controlled precisely - it says no radio knowledge required but there are some considerable things to figure out such as what frequency you need to receive and what bandwidth the signal is that you want to intercept.

The microprocessor interface is a must - it has to set up the frequency synthesizer - without knowing the transmit frequency you wish to intercept or the type of modulation it's guesswork.